# React: How to save previous states in a object with dynamic properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to store some information every time that a change occurs on the value of a input element.

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({})

const addInput = (name, value, type) => {
    setInputs(() => {
      inputs[name] = {
        "value": value,
        "type": type
      }
      return inputs
    })
  }

...

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    addInput(props.name, event.target.value, event.target.type)
    ...
  }
```

I've got an empty object callled **inputs**, and if the user types inside an input like this:

```
<input name="username" value={onChange} type="text">
```

the **inputs** object should have now a property called username:

```
{
  username: {
    type: "text",
    value: : "text-from-the-user",
  }
}
```

but my problem is: When I add two inputs or more inside this **inputs** object, a override occurs in all the properties that isn't having a change.

For example: If I have two objects inside the **inputs**...:

```
{
  username: {
    type: "text",
    value: : "John",
  },
  email: {
    type: "email",
    value: : undefined,
  },
}
```

...and I add some text in the email input, the **inputs** object loses the data from the username object:

```
{
  username: {
    type: undefined,
    value: : undefined,
  },
  email: {
    type: "email",
    value: : "Jhon123@yahoo.com",
  },
}
```

So I'm trying to implement the **...prev** inside this setInput, but I'm having trouble with this, because inside this setInput I say that I want to create new objects if they don't exist:

```
...
      inputs[name] = {
        "value": value,
        "type": type
      }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
setInputs((ps) => ({
    ...ps,
    [name]: {
        "value": value,
        "type": type
    }
}))
```

When you set state:

- you must update state in immutable way
- and `useState` overwrites new value over the old one (doesn't merge like it was in class components)